# Memory management when reading the same file over again

Tags: java, linux, memory

I am wondering if linux keeps something in memory (in order to speed up next time) when reading a text file over and over again ?
I am not modifying the text file. Just reading.

Thanks !

Remi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Linux kernel would allocate unused memory to [buffering disk accesses](http://linux.about.com/od/lsa_guide/a/gdelsa44.htm) (which is why if you use `top` you'd see that, under active usage, you normally don't see much free RAM)

Comment: +1 Most OSes have done this for decades. It wouldn't matter if you are modifying the file or not.

Comment: Indeed, of course, just with any other cache, modifying a file might actually flush /other/ files from it

Comment: It could flush other files if the file grow significantly and there is not enough free memory. If the file is much the same size, it will replace itself in memory and not push out other files.

Comment: depends on usage though? Editors would typically create a working copy of the files you edit, and swap them for the original when you save; likewise, with more modern copy-on-write filesystems, if a file has been snapshotted you'd be saving a new copy. I wonder, actually, how smart the caching mechanism is in such a situation

Comment: This is true. But in the case where you re-write the same file, you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Is this true in a web server environment ? If a worker process opens a file, and closes it, does the file remains in memory for other worker process ?

Comment: It should not make a difference -- so yes. Unless the worker processes are run isolated in different virtual machines; AFAIK with oVirt you can now share (identical) libraries' memory footprint among different virtualized guests and their host OS, but not page caches

Answer (score 1):

In a linux kernel, the read() system call loads your data in the page cache, if this data is still around next time your perform read() on the same location, then yes, it will read from this cache and speed up things.

you can read a bit up on it in this [tutorial](http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=310) and just by researching it in google and other search engines.